# Error on thumbnail_url of Instagram oEmbed response

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

the thumbnail_url included in the results I called directly by oEmbed API responds with “5xx Server Error” (the response code is 404).
This seems to not happen to all posts. It seems to happen to posts with multiple images.
Is this some kind of bug? If anyone knows how to solve the problem, please let me know.

Example of calls with the issue:
https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/BeQeYvGhikG/

The response:

```
{
version: "1.0",
title: "Snowscapes of Shinbashi Tokyo. ☃️ 雪の新橋。人少なくて静かー。",
author_name: "__mari",
author_url: "https://www.instagram.com/__mari",
author_id: 826955,
media_id: "1697990700756773126_826955",
provider_name: "Instagram",
provider_url: "https://www.instagram.com",
type: "rich",
width: 658,
height: null,
thumbnail_url: "https://scontent-nrt1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/20527738f48cda65df8d3bd94b26d524/5B0A2F29/t51.2885-15/e35/p612x612/26286262_351537732029543_9027144447208456192_n.jpg",
thumbnail_width: 612,
thumbnail_height: 765
}
```

Comment: Same issue here, did you manage to fix it? I'm pretty sure I'm not being rate limited because I am able to fetch thumbnails for all post types except carousels

Answer (score 2):

**Method #2, [URL append endpoint](https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/#media_redirect)**:

[`https://instagram.com/p/fA9uwTtkSN/media/?size=t`](https://instagram.com/p/fA9uwTtkSN/media/?size=t)

goes directly to a thumbnail image and seems to consistently work.

---

**Method #1, [oEmbed endpoint](https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/#oembed)**, appears unreliable. Their own example:

[`https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagr.am/p/fA9uwTtkSN/`](https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagr.am/p/fA9uwTtkSN/)

provides a JSON `thumbnail_url`. In Aug 2019 it was:

`https://scontent-dfw5-2.cdninstagram.com/vp/2b20df9f6328b220fb1aa6267efc51d8/5DD21929/t51.2885-15/e35/p612x612/26286262_351537732029543_9027144447208456192_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-dfw5-2.cdninstagram.com`

or in Feb 2020:

`https://scontent-ort2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e15/11358196_1472850273007829_614249870_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-ort2-1.cdninstagram.com\u0026_nc_cat=105\u0026_nc_ohc=kBpTq0BJd10AX8x-qD3\u0026oh=e7110c45ee7a314aa47cb41c01f211f0\u0026oe=5E4E7EC4`

which leads to different flavors of crap:

- `5xx Server Error` (but it's really status 404)
- `URL signature expired` (though recently obtained)
- `Bad URL timestamp` (status 403)